# Magento admin ui after render event

Tags: magento2, admin, adminhtml, knockoutjs

I'm trying to create a custom `text-area` in admin panel and I need to attach the `afterRender` event to it.

**Config XML:**

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="behavior">
        <field name="behavior_field_feed_template">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Feed Template</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">textarea</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Feeds/js/form/export-feed-template</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">export</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">behavior_field_feed_template</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="toggleVisibility" xsi:type="string">${$.parentName}.behavior_field_file_format:value</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="valuesForOptions" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="feeds_product" xsi:type="string">feeds_product</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="notice" xsi:type="string">
                        To generate Feed you need to prepare template.
                        You can do this with existing templates which we've prepared for you or can create your own.
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/textarea',
        'Feed/js/lib/codemirror'
    ],
    function (Element, CodeMirror) {
        'use strict';

        return Element.extend(
            {
                defaults: {
                    valuesForOptions: [],
                    isShown: false,
                    inverseVisibility: false,
                    visible: false
                },

                afterRender: function() {
                    // Do something here!!!
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
```

What setting I'm I missing to achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So. All I had to do is to add 1 line into config:
Feeds/form/template
Then add this template into dir and add the "afterRender: afterRender" config into data-bind.